# Android WebView doesn't work with default browser, but works with Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, webview

My mobile URL works fine with Chrome browser, but not with the default browser and WebView. But some mobiles work with the default browser. My site contains JavaScript; I enabled JavaScript.

My site:

http://192.99.56.153:35555/htmlchat/123flashchat.html?init_host=192.99.56.153&init_host_s=192.99.56.153&init_host_h=192.99.56.153

My webview:

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebviewUrl());
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Is any fix possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the internet permission in your apps manifest?

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to your `AndroidMainfest.xml` file, within the manifest tags.

Also, make sure your view is set correctly (height and widths etc).

You will need to post the relevant log output otherwise.

Comment: Well without any logs, error messages or any other information, it is very difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add this lines and try again.

```
   webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

   webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android Browser, and so the Android WebView, change from OS version to OS version. On top of that, different vendor included a different HTML rendering engine (e.g. Samsung Browser is based on Chromium since Android v4.0).

If you're working on Android v4.4 (KitKat) or newer, I suggest to enable the debug interface so that you can debug your HTML/JavaScript through the Chrome Dev Tools on your PC:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
// Enable some handy features. What are the requirements of your HTML/JavaScript code?
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.99.56.153:35555/htmlchat/123flashchat.html?init_host=192.99.56.153&init_host_s=192.99.56.153&init_host_h=192.99.56.153");
```

The application that includes the webview, needs to have Internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Can you use Chrome DevTools to understand what is the issue? Can you post a sample of the html page that showcase the issue?